# what is so great about having an invariant measure?

Tags: dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I am a student who just started to learn basic concepts of ergodic theory.

It seems like that given a dynamical system, people are very excited to find various invariant measures of the system. But the books I am reading doesn't really convince me why it is good to have invariant measures.

For example, the Gauss map on the unit interval $x \mapsto \{ 1/x \}$ has the invariant measure $ 1/({1+x})$. What kind of effective results can we prove about the Gauss map using this invariant measure?

Comment: Thanks, I was also interested in the same question, what I would say to a non-mathematician, that why one would be interested to know whether invariant measure exists or not?

Comment: Don't know but wikipedia mentions the relation between [invariant measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory#Examples) and [Liouville equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(Hamiltonian)#Ergodic_theory), it seems you can recast the condition of having a invariant measure to having a hamiltonian that satisfy a continuity equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One important case is when you have a probability measure, in which case if a map has an invariant measure, then it preserves probability. This is the proper setting for the Birkhoff ergodic theorem, which presumably you will soon learn.

Comment: why one would be interested in preserving probability? can you explain a little more with more real-world intuition, application, motivation, examples? Thanks!